# Js y Laravel The page has expired due to inactivity

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo el siguiente formulario en java y no se como hacer para que laravel me detecte el crsf.

```
                    <form method="post" action="/turnos/${data.id}">

                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_token()"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />

                        <a href="/turnos/${data.id}" rel="tooltip" title="Ver detalle" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs" >
                            <span class="oi oi-info"></span>                      
                        </a>
                        <a href="/turnos/${data.id}/edit" rel="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-success btn-simple btn-xs" >
                            <span class="oi oi-pencil"></span>                           
                        </a>                                
                        <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Borrar" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                            <span class="oi oi-trash"></span>                            
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar el csrf_field en Laravel lo puedes hacer de cualquiera de los modos siguientes:

Laravel 5.5 o inferior

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

o también asi:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Como puedes notar en el ejemplo anterior, a ti lo que te hace falta es la sintáxis de las dobles llaves de blade al momento de declarar el csrf_token

O si tu versión de Laravel es 5.6; puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente:

```
@csrf
```

Comment: de la manera que tu dices no funciona, si ves el codigo pongo el input que decis, y si pongo las otras dos manera me imprime en pantalla {{ csrf_field() }} o @csrf, se te ocurre alguna otra manera?, de todos modos gracias

Comment: Pues esas son las formas según la documentación de Laravel además no estas usando Java si no ha javascript

Comment: Fíjate que en el input que tú declaras te hacen falta las dobles llaves y yo te lo puse de primer ejemplo @SeguridaIT

Comment: tienes razón Alfredo, faltaban las llaves, igualmente no funciono :( se lo tendre que pasar de alguna otra manera?